# Cannot convert string to date - Invalid Date

Tags: javascript, datetime

I've this date: `16-08-13` I want convert it into `DateTime` 'cause I need to insert this value inside my database.

Actually I did this:

```
date = new Date('16-08-13');
```

but I get this error:

> Invalid Date

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: @Tresdin 2016-08-13

Comment: Then what's wrong with `'20'` + `'16-08-13'`?

Comment: DateTime implies time too? 2016-08-13 00:00

Comment: @Tresdin I don't know if is a good solution

Answer (score 1):

From the [Date documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for the Date constructor taking a date string

> dateString
>
> String value representing a date. The string should be in a format
>   recognized by the Date.parse() method (IETF-compliant RFC 2822
>   timestamps and also a version of ISO8601).

From the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15), a 2-digit year won't cut it. You want YYYY-MM-DD at the minimum:

```js
console.log(new Date('2016-08-13'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the time element to the input string.

```
var date = new Date('2016-08-13 00:00');
```

Your date format is confusing because 13-08-16 could mean the 13th day of the 8th month of the 2016 or the 16th day of the 8th month of 2013

Answer (score 0):

You just have to make the year 4 digits

```
date = new Date('2016-08-13')
```

that will give you this results
Date {Fri Aug 12 2016 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Standard Time)}

which is a datetime object.